# Iterations on a matrix in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need a little help about the way to iterate all the possible combination.

For example, I have this matrix:

```
M = [['RG', 'GG', 'BG'], ['RR', 'GR', 'BR'], ['RR', 'GR', 'BR'], ['RB', 'GB', 'BB']]
```

I need each iteration will be:

```
RG, RR, RR, RB
RG, RR, RR, GB
RG, RR, RR, BB

RG, RR, GR, RB
RG, RR, GR, GB
RG, RR, GR, BB

RG, RR, BR, RB
RG, RR, BR, GB
RG, RR, BR, BB

.., .., .., ..
.., .., .., ..
.., .., .., ..

BG, BR, BR, RB
BG, BR, BR, GB
BG, BR, BR, BB
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: You're looking for the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

Comment: @ForceBru I can't find the one should I use it, because of my strings inside a matrix and there is no function that supports that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.product`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> c = itertools.product(*[['RG', 'GG', 'BG'], ['RR', 'GR', 'BR'], ['RR', 'GR', 'BR'], ['RB', 'GB', 'BB']])
>>> list(c)
[('RG', 'RR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'RR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'GR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('RG', 'BR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'RR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'GR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('GG', 'BR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'RR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'GR', 'BR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'RR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'RR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'RR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'GR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'GR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'GR', 'BB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'BR', 'RB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'BR', 'GB'), ('BG', 'BR', 'BR', 'BB')]
```